# Apache 2 302 error when executing php script

Tags: php, html, apache

This program is 4 years old but i am trying to make it work. https://github.com/msaad1999/KLiK-SocialMediaWebsite I followed all the instructions everything appears to work except I get the following error in Apache 2 After I click the login button. Also I did add a .htacces file in both folders.

::1 - - [21/Apr/2023:15:55:30 -0500] "POST /socialmedia/includes/login.inc.php HTTP/1.1" 302 354 "https://sourcecodedepot.com/socialmedia/login.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/114.0.0.0"

After researching the 302 is some kind of redirect that is not working the header does say login=success but it doesn't redirect. if you look at the commented out code i tried to redirect it to my my homepage but it didn't work. I'm new to php and html 1 have 2 questions 1 I am not sure what ../ means I assume it go up to next folder?
2 how can I get the redirect to go back to the default page not sure what the default page should be. Here is the code referenced in error log

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['login-submit']))
{

require 'dbh.inc.php';

$mailuid = $_POST['mailuid'];
$password = $_POST['pwd'];

if (empty($mailuid) || empty($password))
{
    header("Location: ../login.php?error=emptyfields");
    exit();
}
else
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql))
    {
        header("Location: ../login.php?error=sqlerror");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $mailuid);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        
        if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {  
            
            $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);
            if ($pwdCheck == false)
            {
                header("Location: ../login.php?error=wrongpwd");
                exit();
            }
            else if($pwdCheck == true)
            {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
                $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];
                $_SESSION['userLevel'] = $row['userLevel'];
                $_SESSION['emailUsers'] = $row['emailUsers'];
                $_SESSION['f_name'] = $row['f_name'];
                $_SESSION['l_name'] = $row['l_name'];
                $_SESSION['gender'] = $row['gender'];
                $_SESSION['headline'] = $row['headline'];
                $_SESSION['bio'] = $row['bio'];
                $_SESSION['userImg'] = $row['userImg'];
                //$_SESSION['coverImg'] = $row['coverImg'];
                
                
                header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
      //header("Location: ../sourcecodedepot.com/socialmedia/index.php");
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: ../login.php?error=wrongpwd");
                exit();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: ../login.php?error=nouser");
            exit();
        }
    }
}

}
     else 
{
    header("Location: ../login.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: `302` isn't an error, it's the redirect that comes from `header("Location: ...")`

Comment: I understand that but it doesn't redirect it stays on the index page. i even tried to use header("Location: http://sourcecodedepot.com/socialmedia/index.php"); to redirect to another page.

Comment: If the log says it's returning a 302, the browser should follow it automatically when you submit the form.

Comment: Are you submitting the form normally or using AJAX?

Comment: Using a bogus username/password I get the 302 redirect and a message `Error: Username does not exist` ( error=nouser ) - when you get the error is there an error message and does the user actually exist?

Comment: `../` means the folder 1 level above the current level

Comment: Barmar using submit button no Ajax

Comment: Well it appears the error is in the index.php 1 folder up i added phpinfo.php just to verify and it does forward. header("Location: ../phpinfo.php?login=success")